# Does CapsLock to Escape remapping in System Preference work?

Tags: macos, keybindings, caps-lock

I remapped my CapsLock to Escape in System Preferences, but it doesn't work.
I had to install Karabiner and remap it using that.
Is there a way to just remap CapsLock using just the settings without installing a third party software?

Comment: "I remapped my CapsLock to Escape in System Preferences" How? Where? There's no pref to do that.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes there is in macOS Sierra, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: ah, ok, sorry - I haven't braved Sierra yet

Answer (score 3):

This isn't reproducible, it seems to work just fine.

[image: caps -> escape remapping]

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this too and found a simple solution.
If you're using an external keyboard, make sure to select it from the keyboard dropdown in the modifiers menu.
[image: modifiers keyboard selection dropdown]